# Force error on unresolved symbols while linking static library

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker

Is there a way I can make sure all unresolved symbols in my static library are reported at link time, irrespective of whether they are used in the main program or not?

Lets say I have a function foo() in foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo() {
  puts("foo");
}
```

I have a function foo2 in foo2.c. This calls bar(), which is not implemented anywhere.

```
void foo2() {
  bar();
}
```

I create a static library from these files

```
ar cr tmplib.a foo.o foo2.o
```

Now in main.c, I call foo(), but not foo2(). So this compiles, even though it does not find an implementation for bar().

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo2.h"

int main() {
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc main.o libtmpc.a
```

I would prefer that an error be reported if there are symbols in the library that are unresolved during link time. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc main.o -Wl,--whole-archive libtmpc.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```